# insert rows to pandas Dataframe based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I`m using pandas dataframe to read .csv format file. I would like to insert rows when specific column values changed from value to other. My data is shown as follow:

```
Id   type
 1    car
 1  track
 2  train
 2  plane
 3    car
```

I need to add row that contains Id is empty and type value is number 4 after any change in Id column value. My desired output should like this:

```
Id   type
 1    car
 1  track
        4
 2  train
 2  plane
        4
 3    car
```

How I do this??

Comment: Hi, what was your attempt? Where did it fail (if at all)? If you provided that, maybe the answerers could also point out what's missing about it and/or build their solutions on top of that instead of coming up with possibly unreadably complex answers (at least half of the answers here are as such, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `groupby` to split by groups and `append` the rows in a list comprehension before merging again with `contact`:

```
df2 = pd.concat([d.append(pd.Series([None, 4], index=['Id', 'type']), ignore_index=True)
                 for _,d in df.groupby('Id')], ignore_index=True).iloc[:-1]
```

If the index is sorted, another option is to find the index of the last item per group and use it to generate the new rows:

```
# get index of last item per group (except last)
idx = df.index.to_series().groupby(df['Id']).last().values[:-1]

# craft a DataFrame with the new rows
d = pd.DataFrame([[None, 4]]*len(idx), columns=df.columns, index=idx)

# concatenate and reorder
pd.concat([df, d]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
    Id   type
0  1.0    car
1  1.0  track
2  NaN    4.0
3  2.0  train
4  2.0  plane
5  NaN    4.0
6  3.0    car
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=";")
 Id   type
0   1    car
1   1  track
2   2  train
3   2  plane
4   3    car
```

```
mask = df['Id'].ne(df['Id'].shift(-1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame('4',index=mask.index[mask] + .5, columns=df.columns)
df1['Id'] = df['Id'].replace({'4':' '})
df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:-1]
```

which gives:

```
 Id   type
0  1.0    car
1  1.0  track
2  NaN      4
3  2.0  train
4  2.0  plane
5  NaN      4
6  3.0    car
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
In [244]: grp = df.groupby('Id')
In [256]: res = pd.DataFrame()

In [257]: for x,y in grp:
     ...:     if y['type'].count() > 1:
     ...:         tmp = y.append(pd.DataFrame({'Id': [''], 'type':[4]}))
     ...:         res = res.append(tmp)
     ...:     else:
     ...:         res = res.append(y)
     ...: 

In [258]: res
Out[258]: 
  Id   type
0  1    car
1  1  track
0         4
2  2  train
3  2  plane
0         4
4  3    car
```

Comment: please, can i do this without grpby, because i need data same as is(without sorted)

Comment: But why do you not want to use `groupby`. In your sample dataframe, `groupby` looks mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below using index :

```
   ######  Create a shift variable to compare index
         df['idshift'] = df['Id'].shift(1)
        # When shift id does not match id, mean change index
        change_index = df.index[df['idshift']!=df['Id']].tolist()
        change_index
        # Loop through all the change index and insert at index
        for i in change_index[1:]:
           line = pd.DataFrame({"Id": ' ' , "rate": 4}, index=[(i-1)+.5])
           df = df.append(line, ignore_index=False)
        # finallt sort the index 
           df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Input Dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4],'rate':[1,2,3,10,12,16,10,12]})
```

Ouput Results from the code :

[image]